Remove duplicates from a string with regexp_replace
I want to remove duplicate from a string separated with comma with regexp_replace function in Postgres
Input string: emarian, eiulian, evasile, emarina,emarian, eiulian, evasile, emarina
Desired output: emarian, eiulian, evasile, emarina
Please can someone help me!
Desired string:emarian, eiulian, evasile, emarina
Sincerely, I'm not familiar cu regexp_replace

You can use combination of array functions and distinct to achieve this
Eg query
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT word), ', ')
FROM regexp_split_to_table('emarian, eiulian, evasile, emarina, emarian, eiulian, evasile, emarina', ', ') AS word;

The above query splits the string by the delimititer to value list and performs distinct and then converts back to string.
I would not recommend regex_replace for this.

Yes, but using this function can't help. I need to use regex, because my tool permit me only this

What tool allows you to use regexp_replace but prevents using regexp_split_to_table and other PostgreSQL built-in functions?

I'm using Helix Dashboards

Please update the post with the actual code where you are trying to use regexp_replace. I don't know if PostgreSQL's regex implementation supports all of the features needed to perform the requested operation, but even if it oes, the expression will most certainly be difficult to read (which means it will also be difficult to maintain when changes are needed). What regular expression can remove duplicate items from a string? might prove helpful.
